# Evolutionary advantages of gyri

Tags: neuroscience, neuroanatomy

[Sulci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulcus_(neuroanatomy)) and [gyri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyrus) are complementary views on the very same brain-anatomical phenomenon

[image]

(Note that there is the named concept of [gyrification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyrification), but not of sulcification, but it's the very same process.)

As the main evolutionary advantage of sulci/gyri stands the enlargement of the surface of the brain, i.e. the neocortex.

As another evolutionary advantage of gyri (not sulci) Wikipedia mentions "[increased speed of brain cell communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyrification#Evolutionary_advantages)".

But there seems to be another (as usual: unintended) evolutionary advantage of gyri (not sulci) which I could not find discussed/investigated/analysed in detail: being prerequisite of internal long-range connections of the neocortex in a somehow systematic way (which goes beyond mere "increased speed"):

[image]

I am looking for references where this - possible - evolutionary advantage is discussed.

---

**Addendum**: In the above mentioned [Wikipedia article on gyrification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyrification#Axonal_tension) one reads

> that axonal tension forces between highly interconnected
>   cortical areas pull local cortical areas towards each other, inducing
>   folds.

If this was true (it's only stated as a hypothesis), it would suggest that folds are a *consequence* of such connections, not their *prerequisite*.

---

**Addendum:** In [Gray's Anatomy](https://books.google.de/books?id=b7FVCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA391&lpg=PA391&dq=Association%20fibres%20may%20be%20either%20short%20association%20(arcuate%20or%20%27U%27)%20fibres,%20which%20link%20adjacent%20gyri,&source=bl&ots=4Oe-N2hGqy&sig=q5P41c-u8nAntZKHE3ZO3_WJIuw&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYjL7l3obXAhWDK5oKHQT4B1QQ6AEIPDAD#v=onepage&q&f=true) I read:

[image]

I wonder why fibers passing the walls of a sulcus and fibers connecting adjacent gyri are explicitely mentioned (BTW: Isn't a fiber passing the wall of a sulcus connecting two adjacent gyri? Don't both of them must have U-shape? Is being intracortical vs. subcortical their only difference?) but not the ones connecting the walls of a gyrus (which would be straight, see above)? Aren't there such fibers?

Comment: I think your addendum is a bit misleading; you quote from a source suggesting that it is a known fact, when the source material clearly presents it as one of several hypotheses. The source does not suggest that folds *are* a consequence, it proposes that they *could be*. As to the rest of your question, can you not follow the sources linked from wikipedia as a starting point?

Comment: I corrected the addendum.